# fabricjs canvas, remove mouse selected area

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I use fabricjs for creating lines on canvas.

[image]

But when I draw new line(red line on pic), mouse draws selection rectangle (blue color on pic). It looks ugly.

How can I disabled this selection???

And have something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the canvas's selectionColor property to a transparent color. For example...

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
canvas.selectionColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
```

or...

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
canvas.selectionColor = "transparent";
```

Comment: Looks better, but border line still be visible.

Comment: There are several properties for customizing the selection (e.g. selection, selectionBorderColor, selectionColor,selectionDashArray, selecitonLineWidth). Refer to fabricjs documentation (http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html).

Answer (score 2):

I found out the solution:
just add settings to canvas:

```
canvas.selection = false;
```